# Azure SqlSink Passing parameter.

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

In, Azure Data Factory Pipeline, I am trying to pass parameter to Stored Procedure in Azure SQL(step 2 below). But I cannot find how. Does some know how to pass list of parameter(from input dataset) to stored procedure(outputdataset) and let stored procedure do the job?(in this case, upsert)

Specification

1.Input dataset fetches json(it's list) from blob storage.
 2. Pipeline invokes stored procedure with parameters from step 1.

**Pipeline**

```
{
    "name": "SprocActivitySamplePipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "storedProcedureName": "UpsesrtSensorRecords",
                    "storedProcedureParameters": {
                        "device_id": "*device_id from input dataset",
                        "user_id": "1",
                        "serial": "serial from input dataset",
                        "measured_time": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', SliceStart)"
                    }
                },
                "sink" : {
                    "type": "SqlSink"
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "SimpleCopyInputDataset"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "AzureSQLSprocOut"
                    }
                ],
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "SprocActivitySample"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2017-04-04T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2017-04-04T05:00:00Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "hubName": "yoshinobufuruyadf_hub",
        "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
    }
}
```

**Input Dataset**

```
{
    "name": "SimpleCopyInputDataset",
    "properties": {
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "device_id",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "user_id",
                "type": "Int64"
            },
            {
                "name": "serial",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "longitude",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "latitude",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "location_name",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "measured_time",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "water_level",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "water_temperature",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "temperature",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "relative_temperature",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "soil_temperature",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "soil_moisture",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "soil_ec",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "water_ec",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "leaf_wetting",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "soil_temperature_5cm",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "soil_temperature_10cm",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "external_solar_radiation",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "salt_concentration",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "weather_wind_direction",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "weather_wind_speed",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "weather_instant_wind_speed",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "weather_rainfall",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "weather_temperature",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "weather_relative_temperature",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "weather_ultraviolet_ray_amount",
                "type": "Double"
            },
            {
                "name": "weather_illuminance",
                "type": "Int64"
            }
        ],
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileName": "NormalizedData.json",
            "folderPath": "imported-json",
            "format": {
                "type": "JsonFormat",
                "jsonNodeReference": "$.['sensors']",
                "jsonPathDefinition": {
                    "device_id": "['device_id']",
                    "user_id": "['user_id']",
                    "serial": "['serial']",
                    "longitude": "['longitude']",
                    "latitude": "['latitude']",
                    "location_name": "['location_name']",
                    "measured_time": "['measured_time']",
                    "water_level": "['water_level']",
                    "water_temperature": "['water_temperature']",
                    "temperature": "['temperature']",
                    "relative_temperature": "['relative_temperature']",
                    "soil_temperature": "['soil_temperature']",
                    "soil_moisture": "['soil_moisture']",
                    "soil_ec": "['soil_ec']",
                    "water_ec": "['water_ec']",
                    "leaf_wetting": "['leaf_wetting']",
                    "soil_temperature_5cm": "['soil_temperature_5cm']",
                    "soil_temperature_10cm": "['soil_temperature_10cm']",
                    "external_solar_radiation": "['external_solar_radiation']",
                    "salt_concentration": "['salt_concentration']",
                    "weather_wind_direction": "['weather_wind_direction']",
                    "weather_wind_speed": "['weather_wind_speed']",
                    "weather_instant_wind_speed": "['weather_instant_wind_speed']",
                    "weather_rainfall": "['weather_rainfall']",
                    "weather_temperature": "['weather_temperature']",
                    "weather_relative_temperature": "['weather_relative_temperature']",
                    "weather_ultraviolet_ray_amount": "['weather_ultraviolet_ray_amount']",
                    "weather_illuminance": "['weather_illuminance']"
                }
            }
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1
        },
        "external": true,
        "policy": {}
    }
}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
Create  PROCEDURE UpsesrtSensorRecords 
(
@device_id INT,
@user_id INT,
@serial VARCHAR(16),
@longitude  FLOAT = NULL,
@latitude FLOAT = NULL,
@location_name VARCHAR(128) = NULL,
@measured_time DATETIME,
@water_level FLOAT = NULL,
@water_temperature FLOAT = NULL,
@temperature FLOAT = NULL,
@relative_temperature FLOAT = NULL,
@soil_temperature FLOAT = NULL,
@soil_moisture FLOAT = NULL,
@soil_ec FLOAT = NULL,
@water_ec FLOAT = NULL,
@leaf_wetting FLOAT = NULL,
@soil_temperature_5cm FLOAT = NULL,
@soil_temperature_10cm FLOAT = NULL,
@external_solar_radiation FLOAT = NULL,
@salt_concentration FLOAT = NULL,
@weather_wind_direction FLOAT = NULL,
@weather_wind_speed FLOAT = NULL,
@weather_instant_wind_speed FLOAT = NULL,
@weather_rainfall FLOAT = NULL,
@weather_temperature FLOAT = NULL,
@weather_relative_temperature FLOAT = NULL,
@weather_ultraviolet_ray_amount FLOAT = NULL,
@weather_illuminance INT = NULL
)

AS
DECLARE @RowCount INT;
BEGIN
    SET @RowCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.T_SensorRecords WHERE (device_id = @device_id)AND (measured_time = @measured_time));

    IF @RowCount=0  
          INSERT INTO dbo.T_SensorRecords (device_id,user_id,serial,longitude,latitude,location_name,measured_time,water_level ,water_temperature ,temperature ,relative_temperature ,soil_temperature ,soil_moisture ,soil_ec ,water_ec ,leaf_wetting ,soil_temperature_5cm ,soil_temperature_10cm ,external_solar_radiation ,salt_concentration ,weather_wind_direction ,weather_wind_speed ,weather_instant_wind_speed ,weather_rainfall,weather_temperature ,weather_relative_temperature,weather_ultraviolet_ray_amount,weather_illuminance )
          VALUES(@device_id,@user_id,@serial,@longitude,@latitude,@location_name,@measured_time,@water_level ,@water_temperature ,@temperature ,@relative_temperature ,@soil_temperature ,@soil_moisture ,@soil_ec ,@water_ec ,@leaf_wetting ,@soil_temperature_5cm ,@soil_temperature_10cm ,@external_solar_radiation ,@salt_concentration ,@weather_wind_direction ,@weather_wind_speed ,@weather_instant_wind_speed ,@weather_rainfall,@weather_temperature ,@weather_relative_temperature,@weather_ultraviolet_ray_amount,@weather_illuminance);
    ELSE
        UPDATE dbo.T_SensorRecordss
        SET user_id=@user_id,serial=@serial,longitude=@longitude,latitude=@latitude,location_name=@location_name,water_level=@water_level,water_temperature=@water_temperature,temperature=@temperature,relative_temperature=@relative_temperature,soil_temperature=@soil_temperature,soil_moisture=@soil_moisture,soil_ec=@soil_ec,water_ec=@water_ec,leaf_wetting=@leaf_wetting,soil_temperature_5cm=@soil_temperature_5cm,soil_temperature_10cm=@soil_temperature_10cm,external_solar_radiation=@external_solar_radiation,salt_concentration=@salt_concentration,weather_wind_direction=@weather_wind_direction,weather_wind_speed=@weather_wind_speed,weather_instant_wind_speed=@weather_instant_wind_speed,weather_rainfall=@weather_rainfall,weather_temperature=@weather_temperature,weather_relative_temperature=@weather_relative_temperature,weather_ultraviolet_ray_amount=@weather_ultraviolet_ray_amount,weather_illuminance=@weather_illuminance
        WHERE device_id = @device_id AND measured_time = @measured_time;
END
```

I've found very similar previous post w/o answer. 
[Azure data factory SqlSink, use json as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332802/azure-data-factory-sqlsink-use-json-as-input). he seems did not get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do this with ADFv2 using the meta data and lookup activities. Then have the stored proc call activity that depends on the upstream results.

I can't really comment beyond that as I haven't actually done it, but know its possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so,ADF v1 is not capable for upsert while v2 can with Lookupactivity or TSQL.
I will try to obtain resource/tutorial of v2 with lookupactivity. Thank you.